# VS code not able to open Jupyter Notebook files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image]

Just started using jupyter notebook extension with VS code and it was working fine until I had to redownload VS code because it wouldn't open. Now when I try to open my notebook files it displays this message. I have the extension installed. Can anyone help?

Tried redownloading VS code, uninstalling Jupyter extension, and nothing worked.

Comment: What happens if you click on "open in text editor"?

Comment: Please embed images rather than add links. I don't know the answer but I've seen this fairly often and generally, it seems to require a restart of vscode to rectify.

Comment: Tried closing the application and opening it. Nothing changed.

Comment: If I click on open text editor it shows the file in json format.

Comment: Did you check the python interpreter?

Comment: What should I check for in IDLE?

Comment: VS Code does not come with Jupyter support built in, Jupyter support is added by installing the Jupyter extension, so: just click on the extensions icon in your sidebar, search for "jupyter" and install the official Microsoft Jupyter extension.

Comment: I already have the extension installed.

Comment: Then step one right now is to go to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues and see if that's a known problem, and if not, report it to them because if you have the latest VS Code and you installed the official extension, and that doesn't work, there are thousands of others affected too and either they already know and are working on it, or they need to be told, so they can fix it. Keep your post open here, but report this to the people who need to know and then put the link to the issue in your post so folks know you went through that process.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a similar issue in Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12984), you can try using the pre-released version of Jupyter extension.

I used VSCode `v1.82.0` and Jupyter `v2023.8.1002501831`, it works well.